# Value of Developing a SQL Framework Similar to .NET

Tags: .net, sql, frameworks

With the widespread support of Microsoft's .NET Framework for C#, Visual Basic, F#, PowerShell, etc.., I've been wondering why there hasn't been any similar database development frameworks created (I haven't been able to find any at least).

This lead me to consider developing my own framework, but I can't help but think that if it there was a significant need for something like this, that surely someone would have started a project like this already, either commercially or as an open source project.

My preliminary thoughts about the technical aspects are:

- The framework would be modeled after the Microsoft .NET Framework as much as possible. Personally, I'm somewhat biased towards .NET & T-SQL, but I think that by providing similar functionality to .NET would help ease the learning curve for new developers too.
- There would be an installer of some type with the option to deploy the framework objects in a separate, dedicated database, or include the objects in another database's schema. Also, with an option to simply generate the scripts to create the objects.
- Ability to select which objects to install (similar to how jQuery UI lets you choose which components you want in your [custom download package](http://jqueryui.com/download/)) to keep databases from becoming bloated.
- Support for strict ANSI SQL, as well as vendor-specific versions (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL).

I guess what I'm really looking for is:

1. Has anyone has come across anything like this that has already been developed?
2. Do you have any pertinent insight as to why this would be good or bad idea, either generally speaking or in regards to the things I mentioned here?

**Edit**

Basically, I'm envisioning the framework as providing a common set of helper functions/procedures, tally/number tables, etc...

A prime example would be a function to format a date into a string that could be used with SQL Server pre-2012 versions (SQL Server 2012 introduced this as a built-in function).

And, by framework, I'm thinking along the lines of development within the database (i.e. programming functions, stored procedures, ad-hoc scripts, etc...) vs. interacting with or connecting to the database externally (e.g. Ling2Sql, ORM's).

Comment: What sorts of things would be in your framework? What problem(s) would you be solving?

Comment: Are you talking about something like Linq2SQL or Entities Framework (ORM)?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're after here. Are you talking about developing your own database engine? Or just a framework to access existing database server engines? If the latter, there are already lots of solutions that do that such as NHibernate and Microsoft's Entity Framework to name only a couple. What are you trying to accomplish that already existing products/frameworks don't do?

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify that I'm only intending to provide functionality within the SQL scripting, not accessing the database or manipulating data in a calling application.

Comment: A function to format a date to a string is already there (tostring) and even if not it would hardly required a new framework.  Tally and tables - .NET has lots of those.   Development within the database - functions, stored proc, ... is that not SSMS?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying - the `ToString` method is not available when writing a T-SQL statement, but when writing managed code, it is - from the .NET framework. I'm thinking along the lines of providing similar functionality, but for T-SQL. Also, SSMS is simply a graphical interface for interacting with the database engine. For instance, Visual Studio has nothing to do with a C# program - it's simply an IDE that makes working with C# & MSBuild much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these objects/helpers exist in the database rather than some kind of .Net library, yes there are a lot of these database helper functions floating around and it would certainly be of assistance to gather them up into one consistent library.

I think the biggest issue is performance though. For performance reasons it is sometimes necessary for example to use some hideous inline expression rather than wrapping it nicely up into a UDF. Or it might be beneficial to optimise your SQL code because you know a certain table has a lot of rows or not many rows, or a certain field is selective or not.

This along with security concerns might mean that your average DBA will not want to install your helper functions because they don't know the performance or security repercussions. This is along the same lines that DBA's don't like to install CLR functions.

But I certainly have never come across a central installable library of SQL helper functions, I guess you could take a look on Codeplex or one of the many other open source code libraries to see if such a thing exists.

Go for it!

Comment: I couldn't find anything like this on CodePlex or Google. Regarding your comments about the performance, this is one of the advantages of using a framework, I think. All too often I see SQL that "has room for improvement" in terms of performance & best practices (internationalization, etc...). With .NET, if you needed to roll your own StringBuilder class, you could, but you don't have to in most cases. I'm thinking the same would be true for many tasks performed in SQL as well.

Comment: Also, regarding the security considerations, by providing multiple options, I think it would allow DBAs & developers to have flexible options w/out compromising on security: 1.) a shared centralized database (like the GAC for assemblies) that could be used by DBAs for their own scripts, 2.) developers could choose to include the objects they need & make them an inherent part of their own database schema (like including 3rd party assemblies in application's project).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're talking about, but .NET has been integrated into SQL Server itself since 2005.  Perhaps you're thinking of [CLR integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: I'm aware of the CLR options available within SQL Server 2005 & later versions, but I'm thinking about situations where that's either not necessary, or even possible (although CLR procedures could certainly be a part of the framework where applicable). Consider the problem of splitting a delimited string into multiple rows. This doesn't require a CLR procedure, but it is a common task with multiple solutions that could benefit from being standardized in a common, optimized function.

Comment: But SQL already has a function.

Comment: SQL Server does provide a limited set of built-in functions/procedures, but there are many use-cases where developers need to write their own functions/procedures that aren't necessarily application specific (e.g. parsing delimited text, formatting strings, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate about [entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and  [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify that I'm only intending to provide functionality within the SQL scripting, not accessing the database or manipulating data in a calling application.